# How to make an object into an array reference?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I have this function

```
array_diff(\@DNs, \@prev_DNs);
```

which must take array references as arguments.

The problem is that I get `prev_DNs` as an object from

```
my $prev_DNs = YAML::Syck::LoadFile('temp-previous_DNs.yaml');
print Dumper $prev_DNs;
```

which outputs

```
$VAR1 = [
          'abcdef'
        ];
```

I have tried with

```
array_diff(\@DNs, \$prev_DNs);
```

but that didn't work.

Any suggests on how to pass `$prev_DNs` an an array reference?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It already is an array reference, actually.  So you were actually passsing a reference to the reference by prefixing it with another \.  You simply need to pass it as `$prev_DNs` and it should work.

Answer (score 5):

According to your Data::Dumper output, `$prev_DNs` is an array reference, so just use

```
array_diff(\@DNs, $prev_DNs);
```

Using

```
array_diff(\@DNs, \$prev_DNs);
```

passes a reference to the reference.